# Building Mongoose models for an Express Nodejs API with refpath

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I'm new to building rest api's with mongoose and express and have a question on how to use refPath correctly on my Models files and allowing for an array of items.

Below I have included the code for a model (built thus far) and would love any input on if I'm even close to building this correctly.

I will also include a screenshot that visually depicts the relationships I'm trying to create.

Those who answer questions here are GODS and I appreciate all the help this community has given me over the years!

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const slugify = require("slugify");

const AlertSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  parentId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    refPath: "parentModel",
  },
  parentModel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["orgs", "clients"],
  },
  status: { type: String, default: "no-status" },
  departments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "orgs" }],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  createdByType: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
  createdById: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
  groups: [{ type: String, default: "unGrouped" }],
  stage: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "stages" }],
  children: { type: String },
  resource: {
    type: String,
    match: [
      /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/,
      "Please use a valid URL with HTTP or HTTPS",
    ],
  },
  notes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "notes" }],
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "comments" }],
  priority: { type: String },
  assignedTo: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please add a title"],
    maxlength: [50, "Title cannot be more than 50 characters"],
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please add a message"],
    maxlength: [500, "Message cannot be more than 500 characters"],
  },
  slug: String,
});

//create alert slug from the title
AlertSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  console.log("Slugify Ran", this.name);
  this.slug = slugify(this.title, { lower: true });
  next();
});



module.exports = mongoose.model("Testalert", AlertSchema);
```

Desired relationships diagram:

[image]

Comment: please, what is the error or problem you are getting from you code.

Comment: So what's the problem Herr?

Comment: Just replace ```departments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "orgs" }]``` ==> TO ===> ```departments: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "orgs" }``` and same with others. Assuming ```orgs``` is the name of another collection schema

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Arjun, yea, Orgs is the collection I want to refence and within each of those orgs, they will have an array of departments that can allow us to link other resources by department.  If I want the ability to assign multiple departments to resources (say alerts), will I need the [ ]?

Comment: For the other answers, i was trying to save my self a headache by figuring this out before i start building, no errors so far but much still has to be built.